# Displaying all elements in a LinkedList without ListIterator

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having issues trying to figure out how to display all elements in a LinkedList. I could solve this by having an arraylist to track the index of every element, however I would want to solve this without the use of arraylist or arrays.

The following is what I currently have,

```
public void displayItems()
    {
        ArrayList<Node> links = new ArrayList<Node>();
        links.add(head);
        for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
        {
            links.add(links.get(x).getLink());
            System.out.println(links.get(x).getData());
        }
```

is there a way to display all elements, in a similar method as mentioned above but without the need for arrays or ListIterator?

Comment: How about a `while` loop with the condition being `thisNode.getLink() != null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few examples how to loop through LinkedList in Java (including one you don't like - using Iterator):

```
LinkedList<Node> links = new LinkedList<Node>();
links.add(firstNode);
links.add(secondNode);
links.add(thirdNode);

/* For loop */
for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getLink());
}

/* For-each loop */
for(Node node: links) {
    System.out.println(node.getLink());
}

/* While Loop*/
int i = 0;
while (links.size() > i) {
    System.out.println(links.get(i++).getLink());
}

/* Iterator */
Iterator<Node> it = links.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next().getLink());
}
```

Comment: For the above examples, it require the use of arrays for 'links', I am trying to find a way to do it without the use of arrays.

Comment: No, you don't need to use array. The variable `links` is LinkedList in the above example.

Comment: Isn't the "LinkedList<Node> links = new LinkedList<Node>();" statement to declare an arraylist?

Comment: No. `ArrayList<Node> arrayList = new ArrayList<Node>();` vs `LinkedList<Node> linkedList = new LinkedList<Node>();` - see the difference?

Comment: Oh! I see! I always thought that as long as there is < > it is considered an array. I am new to programming so I did not know about it. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, `LinkedList<Node>` defines linked list containing elements of type Node

Answer (score -1):

You can use an integer as a global variable, while inserting data into Linked List increment this variable.

Write a method in LinkedList class with parameter position. Here loop upto the position, get the data and return the same.